# How to split pipe separated string into array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, split

I have pipe separated string `(sshshhs , 1) | (ee23es , 1)` , I want to split and make an array of object . Result must be like `[ {name:sshshhs,value:1},{name:ee23es,value:2} ]`. I am new to JavaScript could someone please help me .

Thanks

Comment: Research Javascript array methods, particularly the split() method .

Comment: Please show an attempt. We'll be happy to assist from there, but far fewer people will be willing to just write the code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple ways to transform your `string` into an `array` of `object`

One of them could be to `split` multiple times and use `reduce` to make the `object`

```js
"(sshshhs , 1) | (ee23es , 1)"
.split('|') // here we first split with the principal key
.map(e => {
    return [e.replace(/\(|\)/g, '')] // we create an object of your values to reduce it
    .reduce((result, token) => {
        const [name, value] = token.split(',').map(e => e.trim()); // we get the key/values by splitting it (and trimming it by the same time)
        return {name, value}; // we then return the finded name and value
    }, {})
})
```

This is definitly not the most efficient way to do it, but it will help you understand the mechanics behind `split` and `reduce` and help you create your own solution

Answer (score 1):

Check out this code snippet

```js
let myString = "(sshshhs , 1) | (ee23es , 1)";

// extract only the elements
let stringList = myString .split(/\) \| \(|\(|\)/);

// remove first and last empty elements, due to regex
stringList = stringList.slice(1,-1);

//split each element into an object 
let objList = stringList.map(s => {
    const [name, value] = s.split(',').map(el => el.trim());
    return { name, value };
})
```

In this way with one regex you get rid of pipe and parenthesis. Then with a map you extract the name and value from each element.